# How to assign color to GVIS timeline chart based on group?

Tags: r, timeline, gantt-chart, googlevis

I have a dataset that looks like:

```
Start   End      GroupingVariable1 GroupingVariable2 Title
1/2/18  1/5/18   Team1             Project           Goal
```

I'm able to use the `gvistimeline` function in the `gvis` package to create the timeline chart that functions like a gantt chart.

```
gvisTimeline(data=df, 
rowlabel="GroupingVariable1", 
barlabel="Title",
start="start, 
end="end")
```

How do I make the color of each timeline event the second grouping variable?

Comment: I think you want to provide more data so that SO users can help you. At a glance, it seems to me that you do not have any values to plot.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I have to have an additional column to the data that has a defined color based on the grouping variable. Once that is done passing the following argument for bar label works.
`barlabel= c("Title", "Color.style")`

The color column must be named `anytext.style` for it to work properly.